# Play Framework router won't find Java method

Tags: playframework-2.0

I create a Play Framework 2 project on IntelliJ. This is my routes file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

This is my Application class:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.index;

public class Application extends Controller {

  public Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
  }
}
```

But when I go to localhost:9000 I get this error:

```
value index is not a member of object controllers.Application
```

What am I doing wrong? In case it helps, it does work correctly when I use scala classes.

EDIT:

This is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "products"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `products` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws   , specs2 % Test )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

I noticed that I was enabling only PlayScala plugin so I changed it to PlayJava

```
lazy val `products` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Exactly which Play Framework version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using an old version of Play Framework

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")
```

That only allows static method as routes. What I did was change to this version of Play Framework

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.6")
```

That does allow, and actually enforces, non-static methods as route handlers.